# Check number of slashes at end of URL

Tags: php, url

I am looking for PHP code to find if there are more than one slash(/) at the end of URL. For example I want an if condition with following structure:

```
$requesturl = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO']
if ( <condition> ) {
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: <url>");
}
```

I am looking for the *condition* and *url* code. The condition needs to detect more than one trailing slash at the end of $requesturl and url has to be the current page url with only one trailing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the URL has two or more slashes at the end of it:

```
$requesturl = $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

if(preg_match('/\/{2,}$/',$requesturl) === 1){
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: <url>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This Will surely work even if '//' is in the middle of the url . Hope this Hepls.

```
<?php
$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$len = strlen($url);
$i=0;
while($i<=$len)
{
$i++;
$url = str_replace('//','/',$url);

}
$url = str_replace('http:','http://',$url);
echo "<script>window.location='".$url."'</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Beautiful Answer. That's what the answer should be.

Comment: But in current form, it will keep on rewriting window.location everytime, there has to be some if check to do window.location stuff.

Comment: if u dont need to redirect just remove window.location and use the url as u like. I did that so that u could check the url.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$sample = array(
     "http://www.example.com/abc/d",
     "http://www.example.com/abc/d/",
     "http://www.example.com/abc/d//",
     "http://www.example.com/abc/d///"
);

foreach ($sample as $url) {
    echo trim_end_slash($url);
}

function trim_end_slash($url) {
    if(preg_match("/(.*?\/)\/+$/", $url, $matches)) {
        return $matches[1] . "\n";
    } else {
        return $url . "\n";
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Why so complex? Look at the answer of Bikash. That's so simple and working

Comment: that's okay, use which you like. :)